# The type initializer for 'NEIQC.Models.Common.Email' threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, nullpointerexception

While using the below Email Function I am getting error as

> The type initializer for 'NEIQC.Models.Common.Email' threw an exception.

Function code is below

```
public static void SendMail(string Username, string MailContent)
    {
        string error = string.Empty;
        string ToEmail = string.Empty;

        ToEmail = Username + "@ril.com";

        EmailService.Service ObjService = new EmailService.Service();
        ObjService.SendMail(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromMailId"].ToString(), ToEmail, "", "", "Newly Added Vendor Information", MailContent, true, Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPServerAddress"]), out error);
    }
```

To this function I am going through from below mentioned code.

```
strMailContent = Get_Email_Content(strVendorName, strVendorCode, strValidFrom, strValidTo, strCreatedBy);                

 Email.SendMail(strCreatedBy, strMailContent);
```

Why is this error happening?

### Update

```
public class Email
{
    #region Variable Declarations
    UserProviderClient ObjUMS = new UserProviderClient();

    //string strReturnMessage = "";
    string strAppURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APPURL"].ToString();
    int GroupId = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GroupID"]);
    static string staticFromAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["From"].ToString();
    string strError = "";
    #endregion

    public static void SendMail(string Username, string MailContent)
    {
        string error = string.Empty;
        string ToEmail = string.Empty;

        ToEmail = Username + "@ril.com";

        EmailService.Service ObjService = new EmailService.Service();
        ObjService.SendMail(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromMailId"].ToString(), ToEmail, "Jyotirmoy.Mohanty@ril.com", "", "Newly Added Vendor Information", MailContent, true, Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPServerAddress"]), out error);
    }
}
```

Inner exception details:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was caught
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'NEIQC.Models.Common.Email' threw an exception.
  Source=NEIQC
  TypeName=NEIQC.Models.Common.Email
  StackTrace:
       at NEIQC.Models.Common.Email.SendMail(String Username, String MailContent)
       at NEIQC.Controllers.AppController.AddVendorToList(FormCollection vendorList) in 
  InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
       HResult=-2147467261
       Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
       Source=NEIQC
       StackTrace:
            at NEIQC.Models.Common.Email..cctor() in 
       InnerException:
```

Comment: Can you show us all your static field and `static constructor` in this `Common.Email` class?

Comment: @Mr.Fahrenheit: updated the code

Comment: @prd: updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `From` settings  is not well filled in the application configuration file as it's the only thing which can lead to a `type initialization error` + `NullPointerException` in the code that you shown.

The part of the code which throw the Exception will be  :

```
  static string staticFromAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["From"].ToString();
```

In this case, the mistake is in `web.config`

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="From" value="somehing"/> <!-- Missing a line like this -->
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: that's different, I am using another one..When I use the function in the same controller it works but not in the class file

Comment: @BN Check if you mistype the key. And try with  `static string staticFromAddress = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["From"] ?? "defaultmail@mail.com").ToString();`  to see if you got the same exception

Comment: now doing like this `Email obj = new Email();
                obj.SendMail(strCreatedBy, strMailContent);` but getting error as `{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: String"}`